# Updating Data table using Firebase Listener hang browser

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, datatables

We are using firebase Listener for update UI the database structure is below :

[image]

we are sending broadcast using mailgun batch sending, so one broadcast may have n number of contacts (emails) it's may have 300 or may have 1000 contacts as well as we are tracking it's delivery or read or click status so each contact (email) will be update status in firebase database (using firebase cloud function) from the mailgun call back and update it's status and date and time. and it will be updating firebase database, so here we will get notification of updated broadcast using firebase listeners.

Now we are updating the dataTable if the broadcast is selected and while updating browser is going to hang because we will get maybe 100 or  300 callback at the time from the mailGun (depend on mailgun callback, how many call back they will send at a time).  for UI please check below image.

[image]

While updating dataTable browser is going to hang and not responsive.

we are using below code :

```
var broadcastRef = firebase.database().ref("businessListings/" + listingId + "/broadcast");
broadcastRef.on('child_changed', function(broadcastSnapshot) {//it will call multiple time because when we received callback from mailgun at that time database will be update and we will received notification in Listener , it will get notification may be 100 or 300 at a time depends firebase database update from the mailgun.
        if (broadcastSnapshot.exists()) {
            var broadcastKey  = broadcastSnapshot.key;
            var broadcastResult = broadcastSnapshot.val();
            var activeMainTab = $('#mainTabBar li').find('a.active').html();
            allBroadCast[broadcastKey] = broadcastResult ;
            if(selectedBroadcast == broadcastKey){ // It's true when we have selected broadcast updating status.
                updateCounts(broadcastKey);  // Updating dataTable and drawing again dataTable, it will call multiple time because when we received the callback from mailgun at that time database will be updated and we will receive notification in Listener, it will get notification maybe 100 or 300 at a time depends on mailgun.
            }
        }
    });

function updateCounts(broadcastId){
        if(broadcastId in allBroadCast){
            var boradcastDetail = allBroadCast[broadcastId];   //allBroadcast is local array which have all  the broadcast.
            var contacts = boradcastDetail['contacts'];
            var table = $('.broadcast_table').DataTable(); // Initalize data table
            $.map(contacts,function(contact){
                var number = (contact.number == "" || contact.number === undefined) ? "" : contact.number.toString(); //Each number we are assing as a Id for identifying row and updating the row
                var errors = ('error' in contact) ? contact.error : "";
                var deliveryStatus = ('deliveryStatus' in contact) ? contact.deliveryStatus : 'Unknown';  // Getting updated status
                var deliveryTimeStamp = ('deliveryTimeStamp' in contact) ? contact.deliveryTimeStamp : ""; // Getting updated TimeStamp
                var deliveryDateTime = (deliveryTimeStamp != "") ? moment.unix(deliveryTimeStamp).format("MMMM DD, YYYY hh:mm A") : "-";
                var clickCount = ('clickCount' in contact) ? contact.clickCount : 0; // Getting updated Clicked Count
                var readCount = ('readCount' in contact) ? contact.readCount : 0; // Getting updated Read Count


        //Each number (#abc@g.com_Status or #abc@g.com_deliveryDateTime) we are asking as an Id for identifying row and updating the row
                $('#'+number.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")+'_status').html(deliveryStatus);
                $('#'+number.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")+'_deliveryDateTime').html(deliveryDateTime);
                $('#'+number.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")+'_readCount').html(readCount);
                $('#'+number.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")+'_clickCount').html(clickCount);
                $('#'+number.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")+'_error').html(errors);

                table.cells($('#'+number.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")+'_status')).invalidate(); // Updating cell for status
                table.cells($('#'+number.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")+'_status').attr('data-order', deliveryStatus)).invalidate(); // Updating cell for status
                table.cells($('#'+number.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")+'_deliveryDateTime')).invalidate(); // Updating cell for deliveryDateTime
                table.cells($('#'+number.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")+'_deliveryDateTime').attr('data-order', deliveryDateTime)).invalidate();
                table.cells($('#'+number.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")+'_readCount')).invalidate();
                table.cells($('#'+number.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")+'_readCount').attr('data-order', readCount)).invalidate();
                table.cells($('#'+number.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")+'_clickCount')).invalidate(); // Updating cell for Click count
                table.cells($('#'+number.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")+'_clickCount').attr('data-order', clickCount)).invalidate();
                table.cells($('#'+number.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")+'_error')).invalidate(); // Updating cell for Error if any
                table.cells($('#'+number.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")+'_error').attr('data-order', errors)).invalidate(); // Updating cell for Error if any
            });
            table.draw();  // Drawing table
        }
    }
```

Note: We need sorting of the table, searching after drawing table.
it's hanging page while updating and redrawing dataTable Because we will get maybe 100 or  300 callback at the time from the mailGun.